# Black line between cover-img and cover-body

Tags: html, css

I used a cover image to fill the sidebar, but there's a black line appearing between the cover image that is not filled with the body and cover body itself. You can see it in action [here](http://www.exclusinga.com/2013/09/high-flying-lionsxii-sharpen-claws/). I'm pretty sure it's not the border or anything.

Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<aside id="sidebar">
 <div class="cover-img">
 <div class="cover-body">
 <div class="logo" style="margin-bottom:30px;">
```

**CSS**

```
.cover-img {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-position: center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    box-shadow: 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}

.cover-body {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 50px 10% 10%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cover-body:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -80px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 25%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 25%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 25%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 25%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0,rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 25%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
}

.cover-body {
    padding-top: 20px !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue. Possible to include a screen-shot?

Comment: @JoshC Chrome on Windows XP. Not sure if there's a bug, random stuff have been happening a while. There's the trouble when you're a designer. The other time upon selection, there's an automatic white padding. And no one saw it too. So I'm wondering if it's a bug.

Comment: Could it be related to the `box-shadow` on `.about-blog-author`?

Comment: I saw it, but when I reduced the window size it disappeared.

Comment: @showdev To save time and trouble of yours, mind if you screenshot it in your browser and show me how it looks like?

Comment: @user1672694 Yup, me too. Not sure what is happening.

Comment: @D.WONG Very sorry, in fact that increases my time and trouble. Did removing the `box-shadow` help?

Comment: Solved already, thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `box-shadow` on `.about-blog-author` that's what's doing it:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
```

Remove it or change `-1px` to 0

Answer (score 0):

Its your box-shadow that you specify in the `.cover-image` class. You can remove it or adjust your code and designs accordingly so that you don't see it there.

Try removing the box-shadow property, and you'll see that that line disappears.